# I want space between first name and last name and then comma after every full name but I'm getting output as below in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I believe I understand the real question here:
I have created two columns: one with the first name (column "A") and one with the last name (column "B").
The author wants a comma-separated list of the combinations of first and last names, where both names are separated by a space.

In order to do this, a helper column can be created, containing following formula: `=TEXTJOIN(" ",,A2:B2)`

The final list can be created, using the following formula: `=TEXTJOIN(", ",,C2:C6)` (see cell "E2")

... the real problem is how to eliminate that helper column: the following formula does not to the job, for obvious reasons: `=TEXTJOIN(", ",,TEXTJOIN(" ",,A2:B6))` (see cell "E3")

My Excel sheet:
[image: Table screenshot]

---

[This is the table for the question](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4279155/dominique)

Comment: Consider: =UPPER(B35)&","&" The Total salary.."

Comment: It didn't work @SolarMike

Comment: or Consider: =UPPER(B35)&", The Total salary.."

Comment: It's still throwing me error

Comment: but it's not just a single word I have a table with it

Comment: The you need to provide a much clearer example of what you have and what the error is. As you can see my suggestion works.

Comment: I have attached a picture to the table

Answer (score 2):

And with a bit of effort:

[image]

Where & is replaced with concatenate()...

So just to show what I suggested in my comments works:

[image]