# Excel textjoin give me wrong output

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I believe I understand the real question here:
I have created two columns: one with the first name (column "A") and one with the last name (column "B").
The author wants a comma-separated list of the combinations of first and last names, where both names are separated by a space.

In order to do this, a helper column can be created, containing following formula: `=TEXTJOIN(" ",,A2:B2)`

The final list can be created, using the following formula: `=TEXTJOIN(", ",,C2:C6)` (see cell "E2")

... the real problem is how to eliminate that helper column: the following formula does not to the job, for obvious reasons: `=TEXTJOIN(", ",,TEXTJOIN(" ",,A2:B6))` (see cell "E3")

My Excel sheet:
[image: Table screenshot]

I have posted the screenshot of expected output

Comment: My Excel sheet:  
[![Table screenshot][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kS0E.png

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76703094/4961700

Comment: @AkshayGosavi: I remember having elaborated your first question, you even got an upvote for it, and now you just leave that question and it again elsewhere. Why?

Comment: it got closed automatically @Dominique

Comment: @AkshayGosavi: it got closed because it didn't contain enough effort. I've added an example and got it reopened.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that as I'm new to this platform

Answer (score 1):

You need two `TEXTJOIN()` then sum. Try the following formula and make adjustment for narration texts.

```
="There are 5 emp... " & TEXTJOIN(", ",1, BYROW(A2:B6,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(" ",1,x)))) & " and their salary is: " & SUM(C2:C6)
```

Or using concatenate operator,

`="There are 5 emp... " & TEXTJOIN(", ",1, A2:A6& " " &B2:B6) & " and their salary is: " & SUM(C2:C6)`

[image]